# array of string and array of pointer questions

Tags: c, arrays

total newb here. this compiles but still gets errors and does not work. i really don't know much about classes and parameter

the program should first ask for 2 names that get saved on the array of strings str as pointers (have no idea what i'm actually doing there). then it rolls a die in a different class and display the strings from the previous class so rolldice should receive the parameter from getstrings and rolldice should give parameter to the main class. i used // to mark the important points in the code and the other options i had.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

getstrings()
{
    char *str[2]; // or also make a string of pointers int *ptr[2];
    printf("\n1st player:\n");
    scanf("%s",&str[1]);
    printf("\n2nd player:\n");
    scanf("%s",&str[2]);
    system("pause");

    //ptr[1]=&str[1];
    //ptr[2]=&str[2];

}

rolldice(char *str)
{
    int dice1,dice2;
    srand(time(NULL)); // does this really make rand() actually random???
    dice1 = (rand()%6)+1;
    printf("%s rolls %d",&str[1],dice1); //a dice for each player
    dice2 = (rand()%6)+1;
    printf("%s rolls %d",&str[2],dice2);

}

void main(int dice1,int dice2,char *str)
{
    getstrings();
    system("pause");
    rolldice(*str);    //when calling functions should i define the variable type?
    if (dice1<dice2){
        printf("%s wins",str[1]);   //here should i use *str[1] or &str[1]?

    } 
    else if (dice2<dice1) {
        printf("%s wins",str[2]);   //or *ptr[2] or &ptr[2] if enabled

    }
    else {
        printf("tie, play again");
        rolldice(*str); // if tied they play again
    };
};
```

i get compiler warning

[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'rolldice' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

both in main class in rolldice(*str) when calling for rolldice
here link for image
[Image](http://postimg.org/image/jwpj6fiql/)

Comment: How to use pointers, dynamic memory allocation, the correct parameters of `main`,  ... there are many errors, it's hard to fix them one by one, go read a book.

Comment: i have been doing just that for a week but still can't grasp the parameter stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you have a few logic challenges to deal with. In addition to barak's answer, here is an example of one way you can adjust the logic to accomplish your roll. There are many ways to do it, so don't take this as the only way. It is just an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for malloc */
#include <unistd.h> /* for sleep  */
#include <time.h>

int rolldice (char *str)
{
    int dice;
    srand (time(NULL));    // initize the semi-random number generator
    dice = (rand()%6)+1;
    printf("    %s rolls %d\n", str,dice); //a dice for each player
    return dice;
}

void getstrings (char **str)
{
    int c;

    printf ("\n  1st player (name): ");
    scanf ("%s", str[0]);
    do { c = getchar(); } while (c != '\n');  /* flush input */

    printf ("\n  2nd player (name): ");
    scanf ("%s", str[1]);
    do { c = getchar(); } while (c != '\n');  /* flush input */

    printf ("\n");
}

int main (void)
{
    char **string;
    int dice1=0, dice2=0;
    int nowinner = 1;

    /* allocate 2 character pointers */
    string = malloc (sizeof (char *) * 2);

    /* allocate 40 chars each + 1 null-terminating char */
    string[0] = malloc (sizeof (char) * 41);
    string[1] = malloc (sizeof (char) * 41);

    printf ("\nLet's roll dice!\n");

    getstrings (string);
    sleep (1);

    while (nowinner)
    {
        dice1 = rolldice (string[0]);
        sleep (1);
        dice2 = rolldice (string[1]);
        sleep (1);

        if (dice1<dice2) {
            printf ("\n    %s wins\n\n", string[1]);
            nowinner = 0;
        } 
        else if (dice2<dice1) {
            printf ("\n    %s wins\n\n", string[0]);
            nowinner = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("\n  tie, play again:\n\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**build:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra  -o bin/roll rolldice.c
```

**play (output):**

```
$ ./bin/roll

Let's roll dice!

  1st player (name): me

  2nd player (name): you

    me rolls 6
    you rolls 6

  tie, play again:

    me rolls 4
    you rolls 1

    me wins
```

I had a bit more fun with the dice roll program and thought I would pass along the improvements. I wanted to the roll to be able to **handle any number of players** regardless of **whether specified on the command line or entered by the user**. So here is an example that will handle any number of players allowing players to be specified as arguments (i.e. `./roll player1 player2 player3 ...`) or if less than 2 specified, then prompt the user for number of players and input. Let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for malloc */
#include <unistd.h>  /* for sleep  */
#include <time.h>

/* perform single dice roll for player (str) */
int rolldice (char *str)
{
    int dice;
    srand (time(NULL));    // initize the semi-random number generator
    dice = (rand()%6)+1;
    printf("    %-7s rolls: %d\n", str, dice); //a dice for each player
    return dice;
}

/* prompt user to enter 'n' player names */
void getstrings (char **str, int n)
{
    int c;
    int it;

    for (it = 0; it < n; it++) {
        printf ("   player %d (name): ", it + 1);
        scanf ("%s", str[it]);
        do { c = getchar(); } while (c != '\n');  /* flush input */
    }

    printf ("\n");
}

/* compare values in the array for winner or tie */
int results (int *arr, int sz) {
    int max = 0;
    int winner = 0;
    int tie = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    /* test for max occurrence of two equal values */
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        for (j = sz - 1; j > i; j--)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                tie = (arr[i] > tie) ? arr[i] : tie;

    /* find max value and set winner to index of max */
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
            winner = i;
        }

    /* if tie value = max, return -1, otherwise return winner */
    return (tie == max) ? -1 : winner;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nplayers = 0;
    char **string;
    int *dice;
    int nowinner = 1;
    int status = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char c;

    printf ("\nLet's roll dice!\n\n");

    /* if 2 or more names given on command line, set nplayer from argc, otherwise prompt */
    if (argc > 2)
        nplayers = argc - 1;
    else {

        /* prompt for the number of players */
        printf ("  Enter the number of players: ");
        scanf ("%d", &nplayers);
        do { c = getchar(); } while (c != '\n');  /* flush input */
        printf ("\n");
    }

    /* allocate character pointers and dice */
    string = malloc (sizeof (char *) * nplayers);
    dice = malloc (sizeof (int) * nplayers);

    /* if 2 or more names given on command line, assign pointers, otherwise prompt */
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        /* assign players from command line */
        for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++) {
            string[i] = argv[i+1];
            printf ("  player %d: %s\n", i, string[i]);
            sleep (1);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        /* allocate 40 chars each + 1 null-terminating char */
        for (i = 0; i < nplayers; i++)
            string[i] = malloc (sizeof (char) * 41);

        /* call getstrings for nplayers */
        getstrings (string, nplayers);
        sleep (1);
    }

    /* while there is nowinner (in case of tie), roll and test results */
    while (nowinner)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < nplayers; i++) {
            dice[i] = rolldice (string[i]);
            sleep (1);
        }

        /* test status of roll for winner (player index) or tie (-1) */
        status = results (dice, nplayers);

        if ( status == -1) {
            printf("\n  tie, play again:\n\n");
        } else {
            printf ("\n  => %s wins!\n\n", string[status]);
            nowinner = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when i compile it i get the following error, im using ide dev-c/c++[Error] ld returned 1 exit status    .the error is in the makefile.win library i think is the program also what is char **str supposed to declare as i have not seen ** only * to indicate a pointer. also it was not necessary to put **string when calling for the function in the main class.

Comment: `void getstrings (char **str)` is how you pass the address of the array of strings to the getstrings function so that it can assign values. It is just the argument passed to `getstrings`, a placeholder. You could change `str` to `dog` everywhere in the `getstrings` function and it would be the same. The `ld` error is a linker error. That probably means that one of the headers files has a different name under windows. If I recall correctly (check I don't have windows) you can use the conio.h header and `getch()` instead of `getchar()`. The code is all standard `C`, so it should build.

Comment: Also, make sure you have your compiler warning on. i.e. (`-Wall -Wextra`) so you get detailed warning. The code above builds **without** any warnings on Linux.

Comment: Lastly, yes, it was necessary to **declare** `**string` inside `main()`. It has function scope. Unless you declare the stings inside `main()` they will not be visible to your `if..else if..else`. The only alternative would be to declare the string **globally** which is not good practice when it can be easily avoided.

Comment: Fair enough. Get some rest and drop a comment with your results tomorrow. Also, I would suggest that you build these programs from the DOS prompt calling your compiler directly. It is too easy for IDE's to mask messages and make things more difficult than they need be. You will learn much better fundamentals learning to work with your compiler directly. It takes a little more learning, but there is no replacement for the understanding and control that comes with it.

Comment: ok fine i found why i got the error. it turns out <unistd.h> library only applies to linux systems so as i use windows the linker could not find it and so i got the error, now i removed it and used the previous pause on the code to get it going and works fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a partial list of problems:**

- `char *str[2]` can be safely accessed only with indices 0 and 1
- `str[0]` is not initialized to point to a valid memory address
- `str[1]` is not initialized to point to a valid memory address
- `srand(time(NULL))` should be called only once
- Non-standard list of arguments in function `main`
- No return-value type in function `getstrings`
- No return-value type in function `rolldice`

Comment: so i can declare str with index 1 like   char *star[1]   and use      str[0]   and   str[1]   for the strings also about the parameters in the classes when they are being called should i specify the variable type or is it not necessary?

Comment: @Hellion: No!!! Leave the declaration as is, and use indices 0 and 1. You will also have to allocate each one of the pointers.

Comment: ok so i allocated the pointers and also used the index 0 and it worked when it was in the same class but when i separated them i got the following compiler error    [Error] invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')  i declared the pointer as int *p[2] the same as str and used the same index